# jQuery check on wordchange rather than "change" trigger

Tags: jquery, ajax, keyboard, onkeyup

I have a input that the user types a search parameter into, at the moment i have it on keyup to do a POST ajax request to a PHP script that returns search results. however its firing off 50 billion (not literally) post requests in about 10 seconds (as the user types) which slows the whole experience down. Can i use jQuery to detect a "wordup" rather than "keyup" by detecting the use of the space bar?

Does this make sense?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm adding this as a separate answer, because it's entirely different to my first answer.

```
$('#yourinput').keyup(function(){
    var input = this,
        timer = $.data(this, 'timer'),
        lastrequest = $.data(this, 'lastrequest');

    if (timer) { // if there is a keyup timeout still pending, cancel it
        clearTimeout(timer);
        $.data(this, 'timer', 0);
    }

    if (lastrequest) { // if there is an AJAX request still running, abort it
        lastrequest.abort();
        $.data(this, 'lastrequest', false);
    }

    timer = setTimeout(function(){
        lastrequest = $.post({ // or whatever your AJAX call is...
            url: 'yourfile',
            data: { search: input.value },
            success: function(response){
                lastrequest = false;
                // handle response here
            }
        });
        $.data(input, 'lastrequest', lastrequest);
    }, 500);
    $.data(this, 'timer', timer);
});
```

Comment: This one I will vote up. But call me a `.data()` junkie if you want, but you can use that handy function instead of creating global variables. And thanks for `.abort` - didn't think about that.

Comment: I tried to write something like that, but you beat me too it: here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/k7R57/

Comment: @German Good call on `$.data`; I've added it. A little clunky, but there you go...

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#yourinput').keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 32) { // space key pressed
        // do your AJAX here
    }
});
```

See [`event.which`](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/) for more information about this feature.

Comment: will never fire for a single word

Comment: @German: it does however answer the question, however horrible the OPs suggested solution may be.

Comment: yeah thats right - i need single word searches! nice idea though

Comment: @benhowdle89 It's your idea! :-)

Comment: @benhowdle89 See my other answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like a delay for when the user has stopped typing for a specific period of time?

Perhaps something like this? You could add the additional function to trigger a space bar press as well. (This was used just for a Google-Style insta-search, so it may / may not help).

```
$('#Search').keyup(function (event) 
        {
            delay(function(){

            var textboxValue = $('#Search').val();

            if( textboxValue.length >= 2)
            {
              //Perform search
            }

        });
});

var delay = (function(){
var timer = 0;
    return function(callback, ms){
    clearTimeout (timer);
    timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
};
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

You certainly could; you detect the keyup events locally and check them for space.

But you'll get a lot more leverage if you can contrive to get all the search results that match a prefix and send them down to the javascript in a data structure.  Have a look at "digital search trees" (also known as "tries") for details.